# Pandas - subsetting dataframe - getting all values of the outermost index level

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(0)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], names=['first', 'second', 'third'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,size=(8, 3)), index=index, columns=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

```
                    foo  bar  baz
first second third               
a     c      e        5    0    3
             f        3    7    9
      d      e        3    5    2
             f        4    7    6
b     c      e        8    8    1
             f        6    7    7
      d      e        8    1    5
             f        9    8    9
```

`df.loc[['a', 'b'], :, 'e']` works and returns

```
                    foo  bar  baz
first second third               
a     c      e        5    0    3
      d      e        3    5    2
b     c      e        8    8    1
      d      e        8    1    5
```

But `df.loc[:, : 'e']` gives an error.

So how do I get all values of the outermost index level with the `:` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple index you should using `IndexSlice`

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,'e'],]
Out[566]: 
                    foo  bar  baz
first second third               
a     c      e        5    0    3
      d      e        3    5    2
b     c      e        8    8    1
      d      e        8    1    5
```

Or `query`

```
df.query("third=='e'")
Out[568]: 
                    foo  bar  baz
first second third               
a     c      e        5    0    3
      d      e        3    5    2
b     c      e        8    8    1
      d      e        8    1    5
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single value, you can use `get_level_values()`:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('third')==('e')]
```

Output:

```
                    foo  bar  baz
first second third               
a     c      e        7    5    3
      d      e        7    9    0
b     c      e        0    8    4
      d      e        8    7    7
```